# Delimiter causing w3c validation error

Tags: javascript

I want my home clear of all W3C errors.  I have one final error:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://storeboard.com

Here is the code for that error:

```
 if (ErrorFound == 0)
 {
      if (document.frmRegister.tbPassword.value.length < 8)
      {
           alert("Password must be at least 8 characters in length.");
           document.frmRegister.tbPassword.focus();
           ErrorFound = ErrorFound + 1
      }
 }
```

Any ideas how I can keep the same functionality but prevent the W3C Error?

Many Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your script in a `CDATA` block, which will cause it to be ignored by the XML parser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    ...
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the [HTML Compatibility Guidelines for XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use   > instead of   <, which triggered the validation error

```
if (ErrorFound == 0)
 {
      if (8>document.frmRegister.tbPassword.value.length)
      {
           alert("Password must be at least 8 characters in length.");
           document.frmRegister.tbPassword.focus();
           ErrorFound = ErrorFound + 1
      }
 }
```